# Wordpress files upload with no owner

Tags: wordpress, iis

I run our WordPress site on IIS (Windows Server 2016) with Windows Authentication (we use it as our intranet).

I have given the IIS AppPool full control over the uploads folder, however, when a file gets uploaded and hits the uploads folder it has no owner thus whenever we try to view the file we get a prompt to login (Windows Authentication prompt).

How I end up fixing it is by remoting into the server and give it an owner.

Is there something I am missing that is causing this issue?

Comment: Is PHP on Linux a viable option for you to switch to? [PHP on Windows is an ended story](https://docs.phpmanager.xyz/getting-started/supported-platforms.html#php-on-windows-status) and not easy to find someone to support you.